# Add a Three-State Workflow by Code?

Tags: 2010, development, list, workflow

I want to add a three-state-workflow to a list. I know how to add this via Designer but - to keep manual works low - I want to achieve the same goal by Code.

This is what I need:

> 1. Add a three-state-workflow to List xyz
> 2. Assign a SharePoint-Group to the middle state (review)
> 3. Assign a SharePoint-Group to the final state (approve)

I googled my ass off, but did not find a source which explains how to do this. All I found where information how to completely write my own workflow which I do not want.

Any hints/tipps/urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to associate WF to list from code:
http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/09/how-to-attach-workflow-to-list-from.html

Then you need to start workflow with your properties:
http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/09/how-to-start-workflow-programmatically.html

But I'm not sure how to pass data to 3-state WF